# JQuery retrieve ICS file as text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, get

Fairly new to JQuery and JS so forgive my incompetence

I'm trying to get the text of an ICS file (eg `BEGIN:CALENDAR....`) via JavaScript.

I have a basic HTML file:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="btn">Send</button>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="ical.min.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my `main.js` is:

```
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $.get("http://www.instantcal.com/test.ics", function (data) { console.log(data);});
    });
});
```

(I'm testing my code by opening the local HTML file in my browser, eg `file:///C:/.../index.html` and clicking the button)

When I click the button I get the error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://www.instantcal.com/test.ics' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is industry standard for accessing web resources on different domains. It is very important security concept implemented by web browsers to prevent Javascript or CSS code from making requests against a different origin.

**consider this scenario:**

You have link from Domain1 which is opened in browser and asking for a JavaScript file from Domain2.

Now your web browser makes call to Domain2.

If on Domain2, you have a policy to accept request like JavaScript or CSS from only Domain2 and ignore all requests from other domains,
   then your browser’s Domain1 request will fail with an error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but how do I modify my approach to do what I'm trying to achieve? It looks like this error is being thrown regardless of whichever ICS file I'm trying to access (ie I've tried many different ones on different domains)

Comment: just add in your htaccess  "<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>"

Comment: I don't have a htaccess (not sure what that is). Just the html page and the js files I mentioned above. Do I just create that in the same directory?

Comment: its security purpose

Answer (score 0):

After much Googling, I came across this info: https://gist.github.com/jesperorb/6ca596217c8dfba237744966c2b5ab1e which suggested a solution of using a CORS proxy.

So what worked for me in the end was to prepend my link with the proxy:

```
const corsProxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
$(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $.get(corsProxy + "http://www.instantcal.com/test.ics", function (data) { console.log(data); });
    });
});
```